# Acura TLX momentarily flashing check brakes, then dying. What is going on?

Tags: battery, brakes, acura, steering-lock, tlx

I have a 2016 Acura TLX with ~50k miles on it. Recently, it's been behaving quite strangely, typically associated with a brief, but never permanent, flashing of the 'check brakes' light. If [whatever is going on] occurs while I am driving, the wheel will sort of lock (not completely, but becomes noticeably harder to turn) and turning the car off seems to kill it nearly completely. Ie I cannot turn it back on at all. Sometimes this is accompanied by a loud clicking sound when I 1. press down on the brake and/or 2. click the push to start. The key also does not work at this point, meaning I cannot (un)lock the car. Weirdly, if I return to it at some arbitrarily later time, everything will be seemingly working fine. Obviously, I need to take this to a mechanic. But I am curious if there's any obvious cause here.

Comment: Wonder if you have a ground issue, which is intermittant or heat related, so car heats up, ground compromises and after some time, it cools and resumes correct grounding? Starter click, so implying low power, yet later power is fine, makes me suspect something like this

Comment: How old is the battery? Had it tested by your local auto store?